# Sharepoint tools for document version control

Tags: sharepoint, version-control, ms-office, document

Does anyone know of any tools for extending the functionality of Sharepoint's existing version control system for Office documents? It'd be great to be able to do branching/merging, or to store versions as "deltas" off the previous to cut down on storage used.

Any suggestions at all would be helpful.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: How on earth are you practically (SharePoint involved or not) going to handle merging of complex file formats like Office? You're not using source files and svn here - I just don't see how you could even start to attempt this.

Comment: Storing file binary (doc, xls) versions as deltas are impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint document versioning is internal to the server architecture, and cannot be extended.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010setup/thread/67936a2b-e534-4c53-8802-a601eade73ff

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use SharePoint as a Subversion client.  There's no practical way of adding branching or versioning off change deltas without a full rewrite of the out of the box versioning.

If you have a healthy amount of time to devote, i'd swap out the SP versioning system and roll one with a Subversion backend